# Querying an Oracle Database with Dynamic Table names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm stuck with some poor database design where I have to query tables that are named by date.

The following query works when the table names are hard coded with relevant dates.

```
SELECT
  ajob.ORDER_ID
     , ajob.JOB_NAME
     , abim.SERVICE_ID
     , shist.SERVICE_NAME
  FROM
    obscuredschema.A190129001_AJOB               ajob --hardcoded YYMMDD table name
    INNER JOIN obscuredschema.A190129001_ABIMSVC abim --hardcoded YYMMDD table name
               ON (ajob.ORDER_ID = abim.ORDER_ID)
    INNER JOIN obscuredschema.SERVICE_HIST       shist
               ON (abim.SERVICE_ID = shist.SERVICE_KEY)
WHERE shist.SERVICE_NAME LIKE '%BIM'
  AND shist.BIM_AUTH_ID > 0
;
```

Noting the two hardcoded table names (along with aliases)

**How would I execute this same query using dynamic table names?** (There's two)

The code for the dynamic date: `TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate - 7), 'YYMMDD')`

If the first table name were a string, here's how I would build it:
`'A'||TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate - 7), 'YYMMDD')||'001_AJOB'`

If the second table name were a string, here's how I would build it:
`'A'||TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate - 7), 'YYMMDD')||'001_ABIMSVC'`

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to do this . . . think `execute immediate`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm new to dynamic SQL, PL/SQL, and execute immediate. Sadly I didn't understand/couldn't figure out how to implement the 'Ask Tom' answer on Oracle. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write a plain SQL query with dynamic table names.

You can write a PL/SQL procedure which uses `execute immediate` and returns a cursor or something; [somebody asked about that just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520373/append-date-to-string-to-get-table-name-in-oracle-and-do-select-query-on-it). If you're just trying to write this query to interact with some data, that might be your best bet.

In addition, you could modify that by turning your PL/SQL procedure into a [pipelined function](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html), and then you could call it from a SQL query using `TABLE()`.

If it were me, I'd consider creating a synonym (or a standard view which just selects from the dynamically-named-tables), and scheduling a job to re-create it every time new tables are created. That might be simpler than dealing with pipelined functions.

Comment: Stack etiquette question. I was not able to get this to work, but thankfully I found a way that I can move the problem to Python. Do I delete my question?

Comment: Some people do. I feel like it can't hurt to leave questions out there, somebody else might have the same question.