Creating Variable to Substitute in Table Name
I am working with table names that include the date in this format: "yyyymmdd" in SQL Developer. For example, a table will be called "OMR_CM.ccsi_mbr_id_did_20240314". Currently, I have a variable that has to be changed each time the code is run to call the date. The variable is set with the script below:
DEFINE DATE1=20240314
I would like to create a variable that contains today's date, and then can be included in a SELECT statement similar the one currently used below:
SELECT MAX(MBR_ID_DID) FROM OMR_CM.ccsi_mbr_id_did_&DATE1.;
Any help creating this code would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried a variety of workarounds using PL/SQL script, but I have not been able to generate results for a SELECT statement close to the one provided.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520373/append-date-to-string-to-get-table-name-in-oracle-and-do-select-query-on-it
Does this solve for your question?

As you are using define at the moment then you might be looking for this sort of approach instead?

Thank you for the help! Both links were extremely useful. I was pretty limited in what I can do because of my privileges on my work server. Therefore, I ended up structuring a workaround with this code: Declare v_sysdate VARCHAR(255) := 'SELECT MAX(MBR_ID_DID) FROM OMR_CM.ccsi_mbr_id_did_' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');  BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE     'INSERT INTO TEST_MAX('||v_sysdate||')'; END;

I had previously created the table TEST_MAX  as: CREATE TABLE TEST_MAX (MAX int);
